# How can I import an existing React project in Visual Studio?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

How do I properly import an existing React project being developed in Visual Studio Code into Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you open a React application in Visual Studio without all of the overhead of other project types.

When you open Visual Studio (I'm using 2019) there is an option that says "Open a Local Folder". Choose that and select the folder that contains the React application. Once it opens, if you right-click on the package.json files there is an NPM menu that contains your NPM tasks. Visual Studio creates a csproj file and if source control is configured in Visual Studio it will hook you up to your repository.

Comment: Did my answer help you out, rajndev? If so, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. -- Thanks

Comment: If anyone is missing the NPM menu, check that you have the Node workload for Visual Studio installed.

Comment: Which option did you select to create a .csproj? I did npm run-script start and it worked but I don't have a project, nor can I press F5.